# Concat a list of hierachical objects

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a `List<T>` where T has the property .Next.

The List has the following data:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

I want to make this:

```
One.Next = Two;
Two.Next = Three;
Three.Next = Four;
Four.Next = Five;
```

Five.Next is null as its the last element

One should be assigned to a single Variable of the same type.

How can I do this without lots of ifs/while/hacks ?

**UPDATE**

The result variable should not be an anonymous type.

I need a return variable of the same type like IEnumerable> or List>

I forgot also to mention that I use an open generic type not a closed one.

sorry for the misinformation!

Comment: Did you consider using a `LinkedList<T>`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: No, but whats so usefull about it? It has AddBefore and AddAfter methods ok so what? You have a solution in mind?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0;i < list.Count;++i)
    list[i].Next = i < list.Count - 1 ? list[i + 1] : null;
```

Comment: to get my wanted result I have to do list.First(); because I want MyClass<T> not List<MyClass<T>> see my updated question please :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a `LinkedList` as others have already suggested or [`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx):

```
var result = list.Select((s,i) => new { This=s, Next=list.ElementAtOrDefault(i+1) });   
foreach(var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}",x.This,x.Next);
```

Here's the demo: http://ideone.com/Qwiwc

---

> The result variable should not be an anonymous type. I need a return
>   variable of the same type like IEnumerable> or List> I forgot also to
>   mention that I use an open generic type not a closed one.

**Edit**: Here's another approach using a `IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TSource, TSource>> ToLinkedSequence<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input)
{
    return input.Select((x,i) => Tuple.Create(x, input.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1)));
}
```

how you would use it:

```
var sequence = new[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
var linkedSequence = sequence.ToLinkedSequence();
foreach (var x in linkedSequence)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", x.Item1, x.Item2);
```

[Tuple Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx)

Comment: sorry once again a small correction (final) I do not want to have a collection as return value (yes I know I can do collection.First(); with Linq) I want the "One" object return with the .Next property containing "Two" object etc... :) Anyway thanks for you Tuple. code never have seen that cool yeah!

Comment: If you just want to return the element `tNext` that is next to a given element `tCurrent`, you just have to return `list.ElementAtOrDefault(list.IndexOf("Two")+1)`. Note that `IndexOf` returns -1 if the object was not found so you might want to put it in a if statement .

Comment: Hm... sure you understood my question Tim? I do not need a Tuple with 2 properties. I just want a single MyClass<T> return which points via .Next property to the next MyClass<T> and so forth. There is no 2 properties .This(.Current) and .Next . Vielen Dank :P

Comment: But not every type `<T>` has a property `Next`. I thought you need an open generic approach without an anonymous type. You should edit your question and provide (pseudo-)code, sample data and a required result. Otherwise it's difficult to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can created a LinkedList

```
  List<string> s = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
  LinkedList<string> ls = new LinkedList<string>(s);
```

If you do **LinkedList.First** you will get **LinkedListNode** that have the **Next** set as you desire

Comment: how you explain it there is No difference to a generic List<T>

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface INextable<T>
{
  public T Next {get;set;}
}


List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>(); // Where MyClass implements INextable<MyClass>
var query = list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => new
{
    First = a,
    Second = b
});

foreach (var item in query)
{
    item.First.Next = item.Second;
}
```